# generalised eigenspace is invariant proof

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, proof-writing

let $T \in \text{End}(V)$ where $V$ is a finite dimension vector space. We define $V_j(\lambda) = \ker ((\lambda I - T)^j))$ as the generalised eigenspace. I am trying to prove that this space of is an invariant subspace of $T$.

let $v \in V_j(\lambda)$ I want to show that $Tv = 0$.

questions:

1)
Naturally I consider $(\lambda I - T)^j Tv$ and try to show that is equal to $0$, which it does if we can state that $(\lambda I - T)^j Tv = T(\lambda I - T)^jv $ but I am not sure how to justify this equality.

2)

Furthermore, if I do show that $(\lambda I - T)^j Tv = T(\lambda I - T)^jv = 0$ does that mean that $Tv = 0$, if so, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) If $f,g$ are polynomials (with coefficients in the underlying field), then $f(T)g(T)=g(T)f(T)$. In fact both equal $h(T)$ where $H(X)=f(X)g(X)$. This is because scalars and powers of $T$ commute.

2) You don'T want to show that $Tv=0$ because you don't want to show that $T$ maps $\ker((\lambda-T)^j)$ to $\ker(T)$. Instead you want to show ....precisely what you showed.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure why you are talking about polynomials. I thought if we want to show that $W$ is an invariant subspace of $T$ we must show that $T(W) \subset W$, but you are saying that $T(W) = W(T)$? Here we have $W = V_j(\lambda)$ so we have to show that for any $v \in V_j(\lambda)$ that $TV_j(\lambda)v = 0$ I don't see how $TV_j(\lambda)v$ gives $(\lambda I - T)^jTv$ could you explain this? 

I understand part 2) now thanks.